# Wordpress - Add a new Admin Color Scheme using functions.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, color-scheme, custom-theme

In the Wordpress UI, on the Profile page (../wp-admin/profile.php), there are eight default Admin Color Schemes that you can select as options:
[image]

I've found where the CSS for these schemes is created (../wp-admin/css/colors/) and made my own folder with CSS to match.

First off, I can't even get my color scheme to display on the Profile page so I can test it. In ../wp-admin/profile.php it's just this:

```php
define('IS_PROFILE_PAGE', true);

/** Load User Editing Page */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/user-edit.php' );
```

and in ../wp-admin/user-edit.php here's the section that spits out the color schemes:

```php
<?php if ( count($_wp_admin_css_colors) > 1 && has_action('admin_color_scheme_picker') ) : ?>
<tr class="user-admin-color-wrap">
<th scope="row"><?php _e('Admin Color Scheme')?></th>
<td><?php
    /**
     * Fires in the 'Admin Color Scheme' section of the user editing screen.
     *
     * The section is only enabled if a callback is hooked to the action,
     * and if there is more than one defined color scheme for the admin.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 3.8.1 Added `$user_id` parameter.
     *
     * @param int $user_id The user ID.
     */
    do_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', $user_id );
?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endif; // $_wp_admin_css_colors
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get it to display my color scheme on the Profile page so that I can test it and edit it?
2. Once I'm satisfied with how it looks, how do I put the color scheme in my custom theme's functions.php file so I can import it with every theme install and not have to worry about WordPress erasing it with updates?
3. How do I set this color scheme as the default one for users?

Let me know if I need to add further details, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can you post real code instead of an image of it?

Comment: Is that better...?

Comment: Yes Danny, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's wondering: I found an answer! Thanks to help from @Manas Khandelwal, I was able to locate a working site that generated a CSS file for me. It served as a great starting point and I edited it from the basic file it started out with.

Here's the site and I'd highly recommend it: https://wpadmincolors.com/

Just follow the instructions to put it in your theme. Thanks guys!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Not sure - maybe it's outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article, it may help you: https://www.orionorigin.com/tutorials-and-snippets/define-wordpress-color-scheme-set-default-users/

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', function( $color_scheme ) {

$color_scheme = 'your_color_sheme_name';

return $color_scheme;

}, 5 );
```

Comment: Looks like this might help answer my 3rd question, although I tried to use the generator on that site and it seems broken. Thanks for the help on one of my questions though!

Answer (score 1):

Danny, I'd suggest you to use some of the default CSS admin styles from the WordPress, and this is an example (Blue theme)

The location of the CSS is here

```
/wp-admin/css/colors/blue/colors.min.css
```

You can make a copy and change it to match your styles. Then put it in your theme in this location

```
<your-theme-dir>/css/admin-styles.css
```

Next, add this snippet to functions.php

```php
function custom_admindash_colors() {
    wp_admin_css_color(
        'my-color-scheme', // unique color scheme ID
        __( 'My Color Scheme' ), // name of the color scheme
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-styles.css', // URL to the custom CSS file
        array(
            '#1e1e1e', // main background color
            '#f2f2f2', // main text color
            '#0073aa', // highlight color
            '#d54e21', // secondary highlight color
        ),
        array(
            'base' => '#1e1e1e', // base color
            'focus' => '#d54e21', // focus color
            'current' => '#0073aa', // current color
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_admindash_colors' );
```

This will create a new color scheme on your profile with the colors you provided. The main admin styles will be pulled from your custom CSS file actually.

[This is how your custom style will look on your profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2qHi.png)

This should address #1 and #2 from your questions.

Lastly (to address #3), you can use this snippet (credits to Panda from the previous answer) to make it default for all users:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_admin_color', function( $color_scheme ) {

return 'my-color-scheme';

}, 5 );
```

This should work and solve all 3 issues you have. In case you want an out-of-the-box solution with more user-friendly features, please check our free plugin ACOS hosted on WordPress.org:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-color-scheme/

Comment: Why do you have to specify colors both in the CSS file and in the PHP? Would love some insight into this, thanks!

Comment: Oh, is one is for creating the new custom profile that appears on the User profile page?